# How to set ProxyAuthenticationStrategy in HttpClientBuilder?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x, proxy-authentication

I am updating the java version of our micro services from Java 11 to Java 17.
In one of our micro services I have the following piece of code:

```
baseHttpClientBuilder.
.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(INSTANCE)
...
...
.build()
```

where the HttpClientBuilder is org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
and INSTANCE is

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.ProxyAuthenticationStrategy.INSTANCE
```

How should I replace this code, using the httpclient5 package, which is used in Spring Boot 3.x?
There the HttpClientBuilder is
org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder

This builder has also

```
.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(AuthenticationStrategy strategy)
```

method, but in the httpclient packages I do not see any ProxyAuthenticationStategy implementation classes, which I could use.
ChatGPT said, that there is a class

org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProxyAuthenticationStrategy,

but I did not find any like this.

Comment: One strategy would be to ask ChatGPT in which JAR the class can be found and check if that JAR is in the classpath